# OpenGL methods of rendering image (performance)

Tags: java, c++, opengl, lwjgl

Currently I want to render the following image to the screen without modifying its aspect ratio. The problem is that I want the image to cover the entire screen.

[image]

The first method I was thinking to implement to fix this, was to extend the image off the screen. To achieve this I modify the `glVertex2f` method. Due to me being new to OpenGL I was wondering if this method is not the most efficient?

[image]

Instead of shifting the image by using the `glVertex2f` I was thinking if one could simply define the margin/source of the image that one would like to display with `glTexCoord2f`?

[image]

Naturally I would believe that the second method would be the most efficient, however I am not sure about this, is this the most efficient? If yes, is there a big difference in performance?

Comment: It really shouldn't matter which method you choose. Performance will likely be almost identical.

Answer (score 0):

> Due to me being new to OpenGL I was wondering if this method is not the most efficient?

Vertices outside the clip space get *clipped* (hence the name clip space) producing primitives contained entirely within the clip space. OpenGL will not process fragments outside the visible window.